# Table View Cell Button, Change Button Image once Clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Currently my project has a Table View Controller with a button and text on each row. I am having a problem figuring out how to change the image of the button on a particular row once the button is clicked. I already have the function "override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" working to take my application to a new view. I need the button (when clicked) to add the data on a particular row to a favorites variable. Which would then be displayed on a different screen. My button does not change the view.

Currently I have a button event function that is called every-time a button in a row is clicked. The problem I am having is I have no idea how to access a that particular button in the row that was clicked and only change the image of that button.

Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Setting Text and images
    cell.batchName.text = processes[indexPath.item].batch_name
    cell.startTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].starttime
    cell.endTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].endtime
    cell.slaTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].SLA
    var statusColor = UIColor.black

    // Calling Button event function
    cell.starButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteStarClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func favoriteStarClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    // Need to change the image of the button that was clicked 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you subclass the button and override `setSelected` method. You don't need to track the button like this.

Comment: Why don't you subclass UITableViewCell, and have all logic there?

Comment: I already have the function "override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" working to take my application to a new view. I need the button (when clicked) to add the data on a particular row to a favorites variable. Which would then be displayed on a different screen. My button does not change the view.

Comment: @Brandi What you are asking at the original post is totally different from what you are saying now.

Comment: @Desdenova I will edit my original post accordingly. Sorry this is my first time asking a question.

Answer (score 3):

The modern Swift way is a callback closure

- In the model add a property for the favorite state

  ```
  var isFavorite = false
  ```
- In Interface Builder select the button in the custom cell and press <kbd>⌥⌘4</kbd> to go to the Attributes Inspector. In the popup menu `State Config` select `Selected`, then select the `star` image in the `Image` popup (leave the image for state `Default` empty).
- In the custom cell add a `callback` property and an action for the button (connect it to the button). The image is set via the `isSelected` property of the button

  ```
  var callback : (()->())?

  @IBAction func push(_ sender: UIButton) {
      callback?()
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRow` set the image depending on `isFavorite` and add the callback

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

      // Setting Text and images
      cell.batchName.text = processes[indexPath.item].batch_name
      cell.startTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].starttime
      cell.endTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].endtime
      cell.slaTime.text = processes[indexPath.item].SLA
      var statusColor = UIColor.black
      let item = processes[indexPath.row]
      cell.button.isSelected = item.isFavorite
      cell.callback = {
          item.isFavorite = !item.isFavorite
          cell.button.isSelected = item.isFavorite
      }

      return cell
  }
  ```

The callback updates the model and the image in the cell

---

- No protocol / delegate.
- No custom target / action.
- No tags.
- No index paths.
- No cell frame math.

Comment: Interesting implementation with callback! Could you please say how can I change image if my button is programmatically created? I tried this but it doesn't change a state of button: cell.addToFavorites.isSelected = movie.isFavorite
            cell.favoritesCallback = {
                movie.isFavorite = !movie.isFavorite
                cell.addToFavorites.isSelected = ((movie.isFavorite ? UIImage(systemName: "heart") : UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")) != nil)

Comment: could you please give some tip?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Please ask a question and provide more code and other information.